# Upload image with thumbnail and original picture

Tags: php, file-upload, image-resizing

I've been using this script to upload pictures on my website for a year now and I finally realised that changes has to be done. I've been looking all over the internet but have not yet found any proper solution, so I've come to you.

- *This script is currently creating and moving a thumb image into the folder '/images' with the propereties 111x111.*
- *I want it to also upload the original picture, how do I do that?*

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif" || $_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png") && ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 4000000))
  $current_img=$_FILES['image']['name'];
  $extension = substr(strrchr($current_img, '.'), 1);
  date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Stockholm");
  $time = date("fYhis");
  $new_image = uniqid() . $time;
  $destination   = "images/".$new_image . "-thumb" . "." . $extension;
  $action = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);

  $max_upload_width = 111;
  $max_upload_height = 111;
  if($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"){
      $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($destination) ;
  } 
  if($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif"){    
      $image_source = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
  }
  if($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/bmp"){    
      $image_source = imagecreatefromwbmp($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
  }
  if($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png"){
      $image_source = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
  }

  imagejpeg($image_source,$destination,100);
  chmod($destination,0644);

  list($image_width, $image_height) = getimagesize($destination);

  if($image_width>$max_upload_width || $image_height >$max_upload_height){
      $proportions = 1;

      if($image_width>$image_height){
          $new_width  = $max_upload_width;
          $new_height = round($max_upload_width/$proportions);
      }       
      else{
          $new_height = $max_upload_height;
          $new_width  = round($max_upload_height*$proportions);
      }       


      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width , $new_height);
      $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($destination);

      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image_source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);
      imagejpeg($new_image, $destination, 100); // save
      imagedestroy($new_image);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just upload the file into a different directory by using following code

```
$originalImage  = "images/".$new_image . "-ImageName" . "." . $extension;

$action = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $originalImage)
```

;

And use $originalImage instead of $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] in creating thumbnail.

Check by applying the following code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif" || $_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png") && ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 4000000))
$current_img=$_FILES['image']['name'];
$extension = substr(strrchr($current_img, '.'), 1);
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Stockholm");
$time = date("fYhis");
$new_image = uniqid() . $time;

$originalImage  = "images/".$new_image . "-ImageName" . "." . $extension;
$destination   = "images/".$new_image . "-thumb" . "." . $extension;

$action = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $originalImage);

$max_upload_width = 111;
$max_upload_height = 111;
if($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"){
    $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalImage) ;
} 
if($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif"){    
    $image_source = imagecreatefromgif($originalImage);
}
if($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/bmp"){    
    $image_source = imagecreatefromwbmp($originalImage);
}
if($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png"){
    $image_source = imagecreatefrompng($originalImage);
}

imagejpeg($image_source,$destination,100);
chmod($destination,0644);

list($image_width, $image_height) = getimagesize($destination);

if($image_width>$max_upload_width || $image_height >$max_upload_height){
    $proportions = 1;

    if($image_width>$image_height){
        $new_width  = $max_upload_width;
        $new_height = round($max_upload_width/$proportions);
    }       
    else{
        $new_height = $max_upload_height;
        $new_width  = round($max_upload_height*$proportions);
    }       


    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width , $new_height);
    $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($destination);

    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image_source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);
    imagejpeg($new_image, $destination, 100); // save
    imagedestroy($new_image);
}
```

Comment: i am glad that i could help :)